How to Fix "Unresolved function or method map()" in Node Js
This is error Image,
I am use map method for find multiple id's,
and this id to find my product details,
also deatils are fetch completely,
All work fine. but, give this warning.
webstrom this warning how to fix?
so, please help to reslove this warning.

Find returns a single object, there is no need for a map. Directly update the properties you want to change.
const favourite = await Favourite.find({ userId: userData['id'] });

favourite.someProperty = 'test';

